# Text swap from radio for active button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the `fa-icon` for the selected `radio` going to the `menu-btn`, but how do I also take the text from the radio?

```js
$("body").on("click", ".btn-opt", function(event) {
  var $el = $(this);
  var id = $el.attr("id");
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .find("span.selected")
    .removeClass("active");
  $el.find("span.selected").addClass("active");

  $(".menu-btn > i:first")
    .removeClass()
    .addClass("fa fa-fw fa-" + id);
  $(".menu-btn")
    .removeClass()
    .addClass("menu-btn btn btn-primary fg-" + id);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="menu-btn btn fg-create"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i><i class="arrow fa fa-fw"></i>Menu</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="btn-opt btn fg-shopping-bag" id="shopping-bag">
      <label for="shopbtn"><input id="shopbtn" name="toggler" type="radio"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-bag"></i>&nbsp;Bag</label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-opt btn fg-rocket" id="rocket">
      <label for="rocketbtn"><input id="rocketbtn" name="toggler" type="radio"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-rocket"></i>&nbsp;Rocket</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML don't have `span` element

Comment: select the label, read the text?

Comment: @espascarello yes that's what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can wrap the text that needs to be changed in its own element, you can just add one more line to the bottom of your code:

```js
$("body").on("click", ".btn-opt", function(event) {
  var $el = $(this);
  var id = $el.attr("id");
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .find("span.selected")
    .removeClass("active");
  $el.find("span.selected").addClass("active");

  $(".menu-btn > i:first")
    .removeClass()
    .addClass("fa fa-fw fa-" + id);
  $(".menu-btn")
    .removeClass()
    .addClass("menu-btn btn btn-primary fg-" + id);
    
  // Set the top text to the text of the clicked element  
  $("span#topText").text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="menu-btn btn fg-create"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i><i class="arrow fa fa-fw"></i>
  
  <!-- Wrap the text to be changed in its own element -->
  <span id="topText">Menu</span>
  
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="btn-opt btn fg-shopping-bag" id="shopping-bag">
      <label for="shopbtn"><input id="shopbtn" name="toggler" type="radio"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-bag"></i>&nbsp;Bag</label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-opt btn fg-rocket" id="rocket">
      <label for="rocketbtn"><input id="rocketbtn" name="toggler" type="radio"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-rocket"></i>&nbsp;Rocket</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like to change your html,
you can use `nodeType===3` to filter out all text contents in `$(.menu-btn).contents()`, then replace it with the value you want.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".btn-opt", function(event) {
  var $el = $(this);
  var id = $el.attr("id");
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .find("span.selected")
    .removeClass("active");
  $el.find("span.selected").addClass("active");

  $(".menu-btn > i:first-child")
    .removeClass()
    .addClass("fa fa-fw fa-" + id);
  // find out all text content (nodeType===3), then replace with yours
  //.each is not required, you can change to [0].textContent = 'yourConent' if make sure at least exists one text content.
  $(".menu-btn").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
  }).each(function(){
    this.textContent = $el.find('label').text();
  });
  

  $(".menu-btn")
    .removeClass()
    .addClass("menu-btn btn btn-primary fg-" + id);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="menu-btn btn fg-create"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i><i class="arrow fa fa-fw"></i>Menu</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="btn-opt btn fg-shopping-bag" id="shopping-bag">
      <label for="shopbtn"><input id="shopbtn" name="toggler" type="radio"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-bag"></i>&nbsp;Bag</label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-opt btn fg-rocket" id="rocket">
      <label for="rocketbtn"><input id="rocketbtn" name="toggler" type="radio"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-rocket"></i>&nbsp;Rocket</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```